# NSWindow Titlebar with close button

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have created a window using Interface builder.By default window having title bar with close,minimise and maximise buttons.I can hide minimise and maximise button using IB attributes inspector to uncheck those style mask but unable to remove those buttons.How can I done it using interface builder(I am using xcode5.1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable/disable Window buttons through IB but you cannot hide or remove them completely from window through IB alone. You would need get the button reference and hide it. Somewhat like this :

```
NSButton *closeButton = [self.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
[closeButton setHidden:YES];
```